# Relacion con 3 tablas en laravel uno a muchos y muchos a uno

Tags: laravel

Tengo en el modelo

```
public function detalles_ventas(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\DetalleVenta', 'idventa');    
}
```

y obtengo los areglos de esta forma,  en un metodo dentro del modelo

```
$ventas = Venta::with('detalles_ventas') 
    ->whereBetween('fecha_hora', [$desde, $hasta])
    ->get();
```

Hasta aca todo bien, pero necesito obtener los atributos del articulo que estan en otra tabla "articulos", y esta relacionado al DetalleVenta por la llave idarticulo

Comment: Por favor publicá la estructura de las tablas que mencionás con los campos, nombres, etc. Sino es difícil seguir tu pregunta. Por otro lado, `detalles_ventas` entiendo que está en un _modelo_ no en un _controlador_.

Comment: si, me equivoque, lo tengo en el modelo de Venta,  la consulta esta dentro de un metodo en el mismo modelo, luego tengo una tabla articulos,  este articulos tiene una llave  con DetalleVenta, lo que nesecito es hacer una tercera relacion con DetalleVenta

Comment: Editá tu pregunta con la estructura de las tablas. Podes generar las tablas desde acá: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Answer (score 0):

En el modelo `DetalleVenta` puedes añadir otro método para que todo modelo DetalleVenta tenga el articulo:

```
return $this->belongsTo(Articulo::class, 'foreign_key');
```

De esa forma puedes acceder llamando a:

```
$venta->detalle_venta->articulo;
```

[Información oficial/referencia aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse).

Comment: ok, pero como llamo al metodo que creo en detalle de venta, ?   , aca lo llamo de esta forma  $ventas = Venta::with('detalles_ventas')  para unir las ventas con los detalles, pero como uno los articulos con los detalles , como llamo el metodo ?

Comment: pues de esta forma: $ventas = Venta::with('detalles_ventas', 'articulo') puedes poner todos los campos que quieras dentro del with